# ASP.NET MVC View - Display something base on Authorize

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Sorry if you found that I'm asking stupid questions. But I'm new to asp.net and I'm facing a problem:

I'm writing a simple blog to learn asp.mvc, and I want to display an Edit link next to the blog Title if the user is logged in. Currently I have to add the currentUser object to Model and check the IsLogged properties to decide if I should display the Edit link or not. The problem is if there is no logged in user, I have to create an fake currentUser to insert to Model in other to make it work. What's asking is there is any other elegant way to do this. For example we can use [Authorize] attribute in Controller to allow access to an Action or not. There is any similar way to apply for the View ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Forms authentication, this property already exists in the **Request** object :

**Request.IsAuthenticated**

In your view, you can solve you problem doing something like this :

```
<%  if(this.Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
%>
    <%= Html.ActionLink("Edit", url - to - action) %>
<%  }
%>
```

But I think you real problem is checking that the current user is the one that can edit the current blog.
In that case, you can do an extension method **CanEdit** on the **ViewPage** object :

```
<%  if(this.CanEdit(this.User))
    {
%>
    <%= Html.ActionLink("Edit", url - to - action) %>
<%  }
%>
```

The extension would look like something like that :

```
public static class ViewExtensions
{
    public static bool CanEdit(ViewPage view, MyUser user)
    {
        bool retour = false;

        if(principal != null)
        {
            // get your blog from the view
            Blog blog = view.ViewData["myBlog"];
            // check if the principal is the owner
            retour = (blog.Owner.Id == user.Id);
        }
        return retour;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain from where you got principal? if(principal != null)

Answer (score 0):

Make the `IsLoggedIn` a boolean property of the *model* itself. This way, you can have `CurrentUser` equal to `null` when `IsLoggedIn` is `false`. Your view would check `IsLoggedIn` and never call anything on `CurrentUser` if it's `false`. This way, `NullReferenceException` is circumvented.

You can also throw away the `IsLoggedIn` property altogether and check if a user has logged in directly by using `CurrentUser != null`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, but there is any solution that doesn't need to put the CurrentUser into model, let say we have lot of View that require to check for login user and then display something, return the CurrentUser in every View is very tidy task.

Comment: You'll be breaking the MVC model if you do that. The View should rely on nothing except the Model object for rendering.

Comment: You shouldn't fetch the data current user data directly from the view. It should be done in the controller. You can, however, write an ActionFilter to intercept the requests in the controller and save the CurrentUser in `ViewData` to be accessed by the views in the future.